# is there any other way instead of using isPressed() method?

Tags: android

I have 2 activities, A and B.
In activity A I have radiogroup, a CHECK button and NEXT button .
before I can press the NEXT button , I want to choose first one of the radio button in the radio group and CHECK it first so that I can know if its correct or incorrect before I can press the next button.

here's my code:

```
btnNext.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (radio1.isChecked() || radio2.isChecked() || radio3.isChecked()) {
            if (btnCheck.isPressed()) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SecondActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        } else {
            return;
        }
    }

});
```

I can't press the NEXT button even I have chosen one of the radio button and check it.
Please help.

Your answers will be appreciated.
Thank You.

Comment: Put FLAGS? Or a boolean variable and check the status in the"Next" button click?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what the problem is, but you could just create a boolean to check if you're concerned that `isPressed()` isn't working as you'd expect.

```
boolean hasChecked = false;

btnCheck.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // put conditions here to check if it was pressed at the right time
        hasChecked = true;
    }
});

btnNext.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (radio1.isChecked() || radio2.isChecked() || radio3.isChecked()) {
            if (hasChecked) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SecondActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: The problem is that the NEXT button is not working even If I checked one of the radio buttons and CHECK it .

Comment: I have this kind of error in hasChecked on onClick() . The final local variable hasChecked cannot be assigned, since it is defined in an enclosing type

Comment: @kyo declare `boolean hasChecked = false;` as a "global" variable (not technically global) but at the top of your activity.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (radio1.isChecked() || radio2.isChecked() || radio3.isChecked()) {
    //Do something here. 
}
```

The above if you want to check if *any one* of the radio buttons is checked.

```
if (radio1.isChecked() && radio2.isChecked() && radio3.isChecked()) {
    //Do something here.
}
```

The above if you want to check if *all* the radio buttons are checked.

If I understand you correctly, you also want to check some btnChk's click, before you press NEXT. So put a FLAG (Global Variable) in your btnChk's onClick method, if you want to log that if that particular button was presed.

If you want anyone of the radio button checks to be true, use the || condition in the if statement. Then to check if btnChk was pressed do the following:

Declare a Global FLAG at just below the class declaration:

```
public int FLAG = 0;
```

Set a buttonclick event on your button in onCreate():

```
Button btnChk = (Button)findViewById(R.id.YourId); 
btnChk.setOnClickListener(btn); 

private View.OnClickListener btn = new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        FLAG =1; 
    }
};
```

Then in your NEXT button check the following:

```
if (radio1.isChecked() || radio2.isChecked() || radio3.isChecked()) {
    if(FLAG ==1){
        //Do something here. 
    }
}
```

What the FLAG does: FLAG is init to zero initially, as soon as you press btnChk, FLAG becomes 1, if btnChk is not pressed, FLAG remains 0. so in the button click of Next button you check the value of FLAG and do your stuff accordingly.

Comment: Yes . I've done it before but what I want is that if I checked "any one" of the radio buttons , I want also to press the CHECK button first before I can press next .

Comment: It's like this . radio button first , CHECK button is the second and finally I can now press the NEXT button after I done the two steps.

Comment: @Astral Projection can you put the code of that certain FLAG if you please ? I'm just new to this android.

Comment: I'm not going to tell you why, but `if (radio1.isChecked() || radio2.isChecked() || radio3.isChecked() && FLAG ==1) {` won't work.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, yes it won't work, check the edit!